# Azure function dependency injection failures when multiple functions deployed

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am having a problem where I have multiple azure functions deployed on a single app service and I am getting dependency injection errors.

- Azure Function V2 runtime
- Doesn't error when there is only one function enabled
- Restarting the app doesn't help but If I redeploy the same binaries, the error will go away for the first run then return for subsequent runs
- Other functions will exhibit the same error but for different services
- I tried remote debugging but I can't get it to hit any breakpoints or trigger the exception view
- Works fine locally

This is the exception from the Azure Function portal view:

```
2020-02-19T06:34:33.432 [Error] Executed 'Logger' (Failed, Id=edfbcc63-09b6-4f9e-8ee3-81fe50fd9412)
System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'Cloud.Services.Storage.Azure.IAzureTableStorageService' while attempting to activate 'Cloud.Web.AzureFunctions.Functions.Logger.Logger'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp,Type type,Type requiredBy,Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure ,IServiceProvider ,Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs : 37
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs : 32
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx i) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 20
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 26
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs : 44
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize() at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 846
   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsyncCore(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 116
```

Code:

Function Definition:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionStartUp))]
namespace Cloud.Web.AzureFunctions.Functions.Logger
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private readonly IAzureTableStorageService _azureTableStorageService;
        public Logger(IAzureTableStorageService azureTableStorageService)
        {
            _azureTableStorageService = azureTableStorageService;
        }

        [FunctionName("Logger")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("logger", Connection = @"ServiceBusConnectionString")]
            EntityLogEntry myQueueItem,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {...}
```

Startup:

```
public class FunctionStartUp : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public static ServiceProvider Container { get; private set; }

    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        Container = CoreAppModule.ConfigureServices(builder.Services).BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

```
public class CoreAppModule
    {
        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true) //when deployed, all application settings must be stored in azure app configuration
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            services.SetupConnectionStrings(config);
            services.AddOptions();
            services.SetupAutoMapper();
            services.SetupMongoRepositories(config);
            services.SetupDbContextsEFCore();
            services.SetupDataServices(config);
            services.SetupServices(config);
            services.SetupInMemoryCache();
            services.SetupIntegrationServices(config);
            services.SetupStorageServices(config);
            services.SetupCrypto(config);
            services.SetupIntegrationLibraryServices(config);
            services.SetupFtpConnectionDetails(config);
            services.SetupServiceBus(config);
            services.SetupStartupInitialization(config);

            return services;
        }
    }
```

Dependencies:

[image]

Portal Settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the your `Startup` class the register with your DI

Comment: @JSteward Updated.

Comment: @josh Since you only encountered this problem when running on Azure, what is your host.json on Azure? Go to Function AppSettings Dialog to see if there is an extensionBundle in the host.json file, if so, delete it and save.

Comment: @BowmanZhu host.json is essentially empty, just `{}`

Comment: @josh I am facing the same isse. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @shyambabu Do you have a solution?

Comment: @C.Ikongo, I gave answer for this. Please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is file called extensions.json in the bin folder. Your startup calls register in that file. Whichever function app deployed latest, that function's startup call will be replaced with earlier function's startup call. So, you need to take an action that all the functions' startup calls will be registered in this file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't [injected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) `IAzureTableStorageService` properly in your Startup class hence the DI can't find it. Reference the project where `IAzureTableStorageService` is located, add something like this in your Startup class:

```
services.AddTransient<IAzureTableStorageService, AzureTableStorageService>();
```

where `AzureTableStorageService` is your class that implements `IAzureTableStorageService`.